# PHP SMTP server using sockets: connection refused

Tags: php, sockets, email

In one of my personal project I am developing a basic SMTP server in php. It's ready and working when I launch it on its own from the command line; I access it correctly through telnet and it is responding correctly to SMTP commands and I access it correctly also from a php script sending an email using this server.

Now I have an issue when I launch the server from a php script and not from the command line (I do it using `exec` function). The server is responding correctly when I access it through telnet but not anymore from a php script sending an email.

Could anyone help me?

**Note**

To send emails from php scripts I use Mail PEAR extension. When I launch the server from within a script and try to send an email in the same process I get this error:

`SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused (code: -1, response: )`

**Summary**

My server implementation is in `server.php` and the script sending an email is in `mail-test.php`.

1) If I launch the server on the command line this way: `php server.php` and then launch `php mail-test.php` the script is processed normally and the email is sent. I can also access the server via `telnet 127.0.0.1 3535` and communicating with the server normally.

2) Using an another script called `test.php` I wanted to wrap the server management, launching the server via `exec("php server.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");` and then doing the mail sending from that script in one shot. Doing that way, the server is correctly launched (I can access it via `telnet`) but emails sent from `test.php` thus after the server launch raise an error. If I send emails from an another script before killing the `test.php` process the email is correctly sent however...

I hope I am enough explicit.

Comment: How are you accessing via telnet? `telnet localhost 25`? Is that how the php script also tries to send? Ie is $smtpHost = 'localhost', or via some network ip?

Comment: I access via `telnet localhost 3535` or `telnet 127.0.0.1 3535`. From the script I access via the ip address.

Comment: @ValentinJacquemin, I know this is an older question, but are you going to publish your SMTP server anywhere?

Comment: @Xeoncross hi, what I did at the time should be available here: [https://github.com/jacqueminv/PHPMailUnit](https://github.com/jacqueminv/PHPMailUnit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely, I resolved this issue by setting `SO_RCVTIMEO` this way:

`socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => 0, 'usec' => 500))`

The error message I got was not really meaningful.

I hope that it help others facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I have an issue when I launch the server from a php script and not from the command line (I do it using exec function). The server is responding correctly when I access it through telnet but not anymore from a php script sending an email.

It's impossible to tell. Maybe there are different configuration `php.ini` (though I'm not sure what could influence this) files, maybe the PHP executable you're calling is another one (check the `PATH` environment variable in both cases)...

Try running `netstat` to check if there any differences in the listening socket.

Comment: I am using the same PHP binary in both situations. Thus the same configuration too.

Comment: @Val Not necessarily. The `php.ini` file may be different. Anyway, you didn't see any difference on the output of `netstat`?

Comment: I get the exact same response: `tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.3535         *.*                    LISTEN`. How the `php.ini` could be different using the same command line?

Comment: @Val You're listening only on the loopback address, therefore you can access it from the same machine, but not from others.

Comment: in this case I do all on the same machine.